# issue running notebook from RStudio error 127

Tags: r, linux

running on linux mint.

When I try to start a new notebook file I get the following dialogue.

"Create R Notebook requires updated versions of the following packages: digest, highr, htmltools, jquerylib, knitr, markdown, rmarkdown, stringi, stringr, tinytex, xfun. "

I select upgrade and it  tries to install the packages but throws the following error

```
/bin/bash: line 2: g++: command not found
make: *** [/usr/share/R/share/make/shlib.mk:6: xfun.so] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘xfun’
* removing ‘/home/hadwll/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/xfun’
ERROR: dependency ‘xfun’ is not available for package ‘highr’
* removing ‘/home/hadwll/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/highr’
ERROR: dependencies ‘digest’, ‘rlang’, ‘fastmap’ are not available for package ‘htmltools’
* removing ‘/home/hadwll/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/htmltools’
ERROR: dependency ‘xfun’ is not available for package ‘tinytex’
* removing ‘/home/hadwll/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/tinytex’
ERROR: dependency ‘stringi’ is not available for package ‘stringr’
* removing ‘/home/hadwll/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/stringr’
ERROR: dependencies ‘highr’, ‘stringr’, ‘xfun’ are not available for package ‘knitr’
* removing ‘/home/hadwll/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/knitr’
ERROR: dependency ‘htmltools’ is not available for package ‘jquerylib’
* removing ‘/home/hadwll/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/jquerylib’
ERROR: dependencies ‘knitr’, ‘htmltools’, ‘tinytex’, ‘xfun’, ‘jquerylib’, ‘stringr’ are not available for package ‘rmarkdown’
* removing ‘/home/hadwll/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/rmarkdown’
```

RStudio is the latest version.

The goal is to run an R notebook in some  form so if anyone could recommend a good  how to that would also be fine!

Comment: The first line says "g++ command not found". So it seems like you might not have the tools required to build packages from source on your machine. Maybe try running something like `sudo apt-get install build-essential` to install the build tools on your system if they are not already there.

Comment: that worked a bloody treat! thanks.